# Dynamic input file type fields

Tags: jquery

I have a form that will allow the creation of dynamic file type input fields for uploading multiple images. The form seems to work except i am trying to add on every input field that is created the following onchange attribute:

```
onchange="document.getElementById("imagepre' + counter +'").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"
```

But when it creates the field when i click on the add button for some reason it adds it like this:

```
<input class="text-input" id="image2" onchange="document.getElementById(" type="file" accept="image/*" value="image2" "imagepre2"").src='window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"'>
```

I don't know why it keeps adding that extra stuff in the getelementbyid section.

Below is the jquery i am using to add the fields

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 images  allowed");
        return false;
}   

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'ImageBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<p class="field"><label class="label" for="image' + counter +'">Image  #'+ counter + '</label>' +
      '<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="text-input" id="image' + counter + '" value="image' + counter +'" onchange="document.getElementById(""imagepre' + counter +'"").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"><img id="imagepre' + counter +'" src="images/image.png" alt="Image '+ counter +'" height="100" width="100"/></p>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ImageUploads");


    counter++;
      });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#ImageBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });


  });
</script>
```

Comment: Might want to look into using [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-multiple) on a single `<input type="file"/>` rather than building multiple inputs...

Comment: What exactly is `imagepre` that you are passing? Can you log it to the console and mention the error msg?

Comment: `onchange="document.getElementById(""imagepre' + counter +'"")` what's up with the double double quotes? If you want to escape a character, use the backslash.

Comment: Or, use `addEventListener` to attach your event handlers instead of doing in in HTML...

Comment: Mike its actually not double quotes, don't know why that was added

Comment: I don't know if i can use multiple because i need the first image to be like a main image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('...
```

with this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.html('
```